# Why does applying a linear transformation to a covariate change regression coefficient estimates on treatment variable?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

My OLS coefficient estimates change when I add a constant to the time variable in the following model: $$Y_i = \alpha + \lambda D_i + \beta_1 T_i + \beta_2 X_i + \beta_3 D_i T_i + \epsilon_i $$
where $D_i$ is a dummy variable for treatment, $T_i$ is time and $X_i$ is a covariate.

I'm interested in $\lambda$, the effect of the treatment. I added a constant to the time variable to remove negative values, (time is from -60 to 60, so I added 60). This caused my estimate of $\lambda$ (and the intercept) to change, while all other coefficient estimates remained the same.

Why is $\lambda$ changing? I suspect it has to do with the interaction with the transformed variable, but I don't understand why.

Here's a MWE in Python:

```py
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

time = list(range(-60,61,1))
dummy = [1 if t > 0 else 0 for t in time]
y = list(np.random.normal(0, 1, len(time)))
transformed_time = [t + 60 for t in time]

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(time, dummy, y, transformed_time),
                 columns=['Time', 'Treatment', 'Outcome', 'Time_plus_60'])

mod1 = smf.ols("Outcome ~ Treatment*Time", data=df).fit()
print(mod1.summary().tables[1])
mod2 = smf.ols("Outcome ~ Treatment*Time_plus_60", data=df).fit()
print(mod2.summary().tables[1])
```

Model 1:

|  | coef | std err | t | P>t | [0.025 | 0.975] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Intercept | -0.125 | 0.252 | -0.496 | 0.621 | -0.624 | 0.374 |
| Treatment | 0.3968 | 0.362 | 1.095 | 0.276 | -0.321 | 1.114 |
| Time | -0.0008 | 0.007 | -0.109 | 0.913 | -0.015 | 0.014 |
| Treatment:Time | -0.0095 | 0.01 | -0.919 | 0.36 | -0.03 | 0.011 |

Model 2:

|  | coef | std err | t | P>t | [0.025 | 0.975] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Intercept | -0.0776 | 0.252 | -0.308 | 0.759 | -0.576 | 0.421 |
| Treatment | 0.9684 | 0.729 | 1.329 | 0.187 | -0.475 | 2.412 |
| Time_plus_60 | -0.0008 | 0.007 | -0.109 | 0.913 | -0.015 | 0.014 |
| Treatment:Time_plus_60 | -0.0095 | 0.01 | -0.919 | 0.36 | -0.03 | 0.011 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In multiple regression, the meaning of each coefficient depends on which *other* variables are included in it.**

To see this in action, just do the algebra to compare your two models.  The original is

$$Y_i = \alpha + \lambda D_i + \beta_1 T_i + \beta_2 X_i + \beta_3 D_i T_i + \epsilon_i.$$

The second model replaces the explanatory variable $T_i$ by $T_i + c$ for a constant $c.$ To track the differences between the models I will prime all the new coefficients (and even the new error term).  Then I will use rules of arithmetic to rewrite the second model in a form directly comparable to the first; namely, as a linear combination of the variables $1,$ $D_i,$ $T_i,$ $X_i,$ $D_iT_i,$ and a random error:

$$\begin{aligned}
Y_i &= \alpha^\prime + \lambda^\prime D_i + \beta_1^\prime (T_i+c) + \beta_2^\prime X_i + \beta_3^\prime D_i (T_i+c) + \epsilon_i^\prime\\
&=(\alpha^\prime + \beta_1^\prime c) + (\lambda^\prime + \beta_3^\prime c)D_i + \beta_1^\prime T_i + \beta_2^\prime X_i + \beta_3^\prime D_i T_i + \epsilon^\prime _i.
\end{aligned}$$

Comparing the coefficients (and random errors) to those of the first model (and recalling the assumption that $E[\epsilon_i] = 0 = E[\epsilon^\prime _i],$ which pins down the intercept terms) immediately produces these equalities:

$$\begin{aligned}
&\alpha = \alpha^\prime + \beta_1^\prime c\\
&\lambda = \lambda^\prime + \beta_3^\prime c\\
&\beta_1 = \beta_1^\prime\\
&\beta_2 = \beta_2^\prime\\
&\beta_3 = \beta_3^\prime\\
&\epsilon_i = \epsilon_i^\prime
\end{aligned}$$

*The intercept $\alpha$ and the $D_i$ coefficient $\lambda$ potentially change.*  If you like, you may solve for the new coefficients in terms of the old, yielding

> $$\begin{aligned}
> &\alpha^\prime = \alpha - \beta_1 c\\
> &\lambda^\prime = \lambda - \beta_3 c.
> \end{aligned}$$

(I wrote "potentially" because when $\beta_1 = 0$ the intercept $\alpha$ does not change and when $\beta_3=0$ the $D_i$ coefficient $\lambda$ does not change.)

Expect these differences in the model formulation to be reflected in your *estimates* of the parameters.  Indeed, a similar analysis shows the estimates will undergo the same transformations.

---

Generally, a linear regression model takes the matrix form

$$h(E[Y]) = X\beta$$

(where the (optional) $h$ is "link function" of generalized linear modeling).

When you transform the variables (columns of $X$) you are right-multiplying the model matrix $X$ by a (usually) invertible matrix $A,$ making the new model

$$h(E[Y]) = (XA)\beta^\prime = X(A\beta^\prime).$$

(according to the associative property of matrix multiplication).  Comparing the two formulations shows

$$A\beta^\prime = \beta$$

and, when $A$ is invertible, we deduce

> $$\beta^\prime = A^{-1}\beta.$$

#### Moral

*Invertible linear transformations of the explanatory variables in a linear regression model yield the same model, expressed with different coefficients.*  They merely cause a *change of parameterization* without altering the relationships between the explanatory ("independent") and response ("dependent") variables.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this has interesting consequences for empirical work. It seems that the event-study standard is to parameterize time as "time since event" as in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2729691) whereas the interrupted time series standard is to parameterize time starting at 0, as in [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/46/1/348/2622842). 

So, $\lambda_{event study} = \lambda_{ITS} + \beta_{3, ITS} * c $